# Is it possible to have multiple Terra Swords?

Tags: terraria

For the terra sword I need

- Blood Butcherer
- Muramasa
- Blade of Grass
- Fiery Greatsword
- True Excalibur
- Broken Hero Sword

All swords are craftable but not the Muramasa. That can be found in the dungeon. I faced the problem, that I opened all chests in the dungeon and only found one Muramasa. So it is only possible to find only 1 Muramasa? Or can I farm this sword?

Comment: You can always create another world to farm the dungeon there, no?

Comment: For sure, but i faced its random generated. So it is possible to have more than one murasama per world. Thanks to [Terraria Forum](https://forums.terraria.org/index.php?forums/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there are no more golden chests in the dungeon, you can create an artificial lake to fish for [Dungeon Crates](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dungeon_Crate), which will yield [Golden Lock Boxes](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Golden_Lock_Box), each of which will have a chance of giving you a Muramasa.

However, your chances are slim. Dungeon crates are very rare, at aproximately 1.78% chance at 100 fishing power and using crate potions (20% chance to get a crate, and 8.9% chance of that crate being a dungeon crate). Not only that, but only 1 in 6 dungeon crates will actually yield a Golden Lock Box, reducing your chances to only about 0.29% to get a box. Finally, a Golden Lock box has only a 1 in 7 chance of yielding a Muramasa, reducing your chance even further to about 0.04%. That's about 1 Muramasa for every 2500 fishing tries!

I don't know about you, but I don't find that very fun. Much easier to just create a new world, defeat Skeletron again (should be easy with high-tier equipment) and grab the Muramasa from the new dungeon.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. I have gotten many Terrablades, as they are somewhat easy to get endgame, especially if you have multiple Muramasa's in your dungeon.